Cordova and MySQL URL API
I am currently building a fairly basic Cordova application academically.  Previous experience of this has been where I have been provided with an API to a database to use in the app.  I have built a database in MySQL workbench and would like my Cordova app to fetch data from there.  Is this possible? Any guidance would be gratefully received.
I have tried creating a server.js file within the directory which has been successful in postman to get, but not post but don't know how I would code this into my index.js.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

const mysql = require('mysql2');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '**********',
    database: '*****',
insecureAuth : true
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to the MySQL database');
});

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/Catalogue', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM Catalogue';

connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(results);
});
});

app.post('/Catalogue', (req, res) => {
    const {Drug, Strength, Form, Pack_Size, Adult_Box_Item, Paed_Box_Item, Shelf_Location, Supplier_ID,              Min_Level, Current_Level} = req.body;
    const sql = `INSERT INTO Catalogue (Drug, Strength, Form, Pack_Size, Adult_Box_Item, Paed_Box_Item, Shelf_Location, Supplier_ID, Min_Level, Current_Level) VALUES ('${Drug}', '${Strength}', '${Form}',  '${Pack_Size}', '${Adult_Box_Item}', '${Paed_Box_Item}', '${Shelf_Location}', '${Supplier_ID}', '${Min_Level}', '${Current_Level}')`;

connection.query(sql, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send('Item created successfully');
});
});

